# XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 12448

Tags: apache, xampp

I got this problem, and I can't find the solution on web

```
21:51:01  [Apache]  Problem detected!
21:51:01  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 12448!
21:51:01  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
21:51:01  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
21:51:01  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
21:51:01  [Apache]  Problem detected!
21:51:01  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 12448!
21:51:01  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
21:51:01  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
21:51:01  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
21:51:01  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
21:51:02  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
21:51:03  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
21:51:03  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
21:51:03  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
21:51:03  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
21:51:03  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
21:51:03  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
21:51:03  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
21:51:03  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Its PID 12448, not PID 4 !!! How to solve it ?

P.S
It's no problem after just download the xampp, then I install Joomla! and get this problem...

Comment: so? pids are essentially random-ish numbers. every process gets one, and you'll probably get a DIFFERENT pid every time you start something up. the actual value of the pid isn't significant (or even useful) except at the exact moment this log message was generated.

Comment: Just run it as an administrator. But even that will not work if you have the WWW process thingy running. So you'll have to go to google and search how to turn that off. I'd give you more details regarding this but I'd rather not write a paragraph in the comments. I'll try and create an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming Skype is running on your system. If so then turn it off. Skype usually runs on port 80 or port 443.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the things to fix mentioned by RepeaterCreeper, on a windows machine you can find the application (executable) by process id:

```
netstat -a -b -o
tasklist | findstr /C:"<pid>"
```

The first command will list all the processes, PIDs, associated process executable name. The second command will find the executable name by PID

More help on usage:

```
netstat /?
tasklist /?
```

To save the results to a file for the commands, use "> file.txt" switch. E.g.:

```
tasklist | findstr /C:"2342" > t.txt
```

The above command will save the output to a file named "t.txt" in current folder. Stop those processes if possible. Or else, configure XAMPP to use a different port in the configuration dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem is that port 80 is by default being used by a service that is installed by default into Windows 10. So what you need to do is turn that off. I'll go over them step by step on how to do this down below.

---

1. Press <kbd>Window + R</kbd>.
2. Type in the run box "services.msc".
3. Now scroll down near the bottom you will see "World Wide Web ... " (I don't know the fully name so just look for something like 'World Wide Web').
4. Now you'll see that it is set on AUTOMATIC as the startup type or whatever it was. Double click or right click and you will see a dialog box pop up.
5. Press the <kbd>STOP</kbd> button to turn off the service.

OPTIONAL

1. Change it to MANUAL as the startup type.

---

Now that's out of the way restart your computer if necessary (But I think you don't need it, however I would recommend it since I'm not sure whether it needs to be restarted or not). And once you've done that run XAMPP as an administrator by simply right clicking and pressing <kbd>Run as Administrator</kbd> and that should work. If it doesn't then I don't know how to help you. That was the way I did it when I was having this problem.

---

NOTE: Skype may also be a problem as pointed out in the comments. If you have skype please following the following.

1. Open up Skype.
2. Go to Options
3. Go to Connections
4. Then you'll see a check-box that is labeled "Use Port 80 or 443 as an alternative for incoming connections.".
5. Tick that box and restart your Skype then turn it off.

Comment: You mean "World Wide Web Publishing Service" ? I confirm that its already stop it... :(

Comment: @SuiKiNg Hmmm have you tried running it as an administrator? If so then I don't know any other way to help you. I'm only sharing the ways I've tested and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Xampp control, click config, open Apache config file (httpd.conf) and set 
Listen 80 to Listen 8080 or some port of your choice, stop / start the apache process and it'll resolve the conflict.

If you wish Apache to listen to port 80 only, you will need to stop conflicting Application or configure that app to use another port.